# A cube with colors

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, three-dimensional

[image: overview]

---

There's a word encrypted in this mysterious cube. Can you find out what it says?
(See end of post for 3D model)

---

[image: bluered]
[image: yellowblue]
[image: greenyellow]
[image: redgreen]

[image]

---

[>>SPOILER: Now that the puzzle has been solved you may have this 3D model<<](http://www.viewstl.com/?embedded&url=https://www.dropbox.com/s/96oqro2usx1cuzl/cube.stl?dl=1&edges=yes&shading=wireframe&rotation=yes&orientation=bottom&noborder=yes%22%20style=%22border:0;margin:0;width:100%;height:100%;%22)

Comment: Reminds me a lot from that one maze in The Room, I assume that just like that puzzle, the solution here will involve rotating layers. There doesn't seem to be a defined start/endpoint... but it seems fairly clear that this is a maze. There's a large possibility that we're trying to find a loop that passes through every line segment. 
EDIT: Aaaand that possibility went down the drain. Too many exits from the bottom layer, not enough links in the layer above.

Comment: The four pictures are the corners of the cube from the side, correct?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the answer is

> stack

Explanation:

> If you look at the cube positioned with its blue face looking at 'north', and the purple side towards you, every layer has a letter-shaped pattern in the strings. You can already see the first S in the 3-dimensional picture provided in the question.
>  Supposing that the purple strings all connect two different sides, this is how each layer may look like:
>  [image]
>  or:
>  [image]
>  Both of these look like saying 'STACK'.

Added by OP:

> [image: the real thing this is]

Answer (score 1):

Parital Answer

Note: (I won't have time to push this further right now, so by all means, someone pick it up and run with it)

The cube is actually:

> A set of 5 tiles.

Ideas:

> Each tile has two large faces and I think that's where the letters are.
>  All of the lines on each tile need to form a closed loop.

Picture:

> [image: First Tile]

PS:

> It still remains to be seen if you are indeed funny.